# VB6 SendMessage to send custom data type

Tags: vb6, ipc, sendmessage

I'm currently successfully using Win32 API's SendMessage function to send text between two threads using the WM_SETTEXT parameter.

What I would like to do is send a custom data type instead of primitive data types.

So let's say I have

```
Type myType
    a as Integer
    b(5) as Boolean
    d(15) as Double
End Type
Dim tmp as myType
```

I would like to be able to:

```
Call SendMessage(dstHWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, tmp)
```

I am guessing I would have to use WM_COPYDATA or similar, but the other issue is this produces a error because my data type cannot be casted into Any, per function definition:

```
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long
```

Is it possible to coax this conversion? Or is there an alternative best-practices method (fast and optimal)?

Comment: Just different threads in the same process (which is difficult to do safely in VB6) or different processes? The latter is much stricter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the last parameter of `SendMessage` as `byref lParam as myType`.

You are, however, abusing the messaging system. It's only fine while you know what you're doing and you're sure no system-default procesing logic will ever be applied to that message.

---

To clarify, on the receiving end, you're doing the following to get the data.
First, you declare your message processing routine with the last parameter being `ByVal lParam As Long`. Also have a function:

```
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
```

Then, when you receive a message:

```
if uMsg = WM_SETTEXT then
  dim t as myType
  copymemory t, byval lParam, len(t)

  'Using t here
end if
```

---

To clarify a bit further.

Because all threads are inside one process, you can simply share pointers and do that by the mean of `WM_COPYDATA`. You'll only need the first member of the [`COPYDATASTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

On the sending end, you set `COPYDATASTRUCT.dwData = VarPrt(your_struct)`.

On the receiving end, you do that same `CopyMemory` thing shown above.

Note that if your message processing routine is only going to receive that single message (and no other messages), then you can simply declare its last parameter as `ByRef lParam As myType` and use it directly, avoiding the copying.

Comment: If I do this, the last param must also be ByRef (User defined types may not be passed byval). So lets say I pass it by ref... how do i go about receiving in the destination thread? Currently, I am setting a textbox's text by sendmessage to the textbox's hwnd; user defined types dont have an hwnd though

Comment: Thanks for the help so far Greg. This seems to work: SendMessage sends a ByVal VarPtr(my_struct). My Textbox receives this pointer as a string, which I typecast back to Long. I use the RtlMoveMemory function to dereference the pointer back to my user defined type. There is just 1 issue left: strings in the UDT only send their first character and not the entire string. This is actually okay for my purposes since my UDT is just ints,doubles,and bools.. but just out of curiosity before I close this question, is there a way to get the full string sizes?

Comment: @AuthmanApatira Strings are passed as pointers, not actual data. You need to deference them as well when using this technique. Have you seen my last edit, suggesting `ByRef lParam As myType` on the receiving end?

Comment: I did... but Im not sure how to implement that. VB6 to the best of my knowledge doesnt actually expose message handling. The best I can do is bind to pre-defined events. In my case, I am doing my processing in the (on)changed event of the receiving textbox (defined by its hwnd). When the received data is presented to me, it is already a string version of the pointer long passed by sendmessage with the above technique

Comment: MyOrigWndProc = SetWindowLongPtr(myhWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, AddressOf NewWndProc) where myhWnd is your window's handle and "NewWndProc(ByVal myhWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long" is public function in a module that will replace the default window message processing routine. At the end of NewWndProc be sure to call  NewWndProc = CallWindowProc(MyOrigWndProc, myhWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam) and before your window unloads be sure to call "SetWindowLongPtr myhWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, MyOrigWndProc" to unload properly.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a Memory Mapped File?

```
'Write to MyMMF

Private Function writeMyType(newMyType As myType)

    hMMF = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, False, "MyMMF")

    If hMMF = 0 Then
        hMMF = CreateFileMapping(-1, 0, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, LenB(newMyType), "MyMMF")
    End If

    If Not hMMF = 0 Then
        pMemfile = MapViewOfFile(hMMF, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0)
        RtlMoveMemory1 pMemfile, ByVal newMyType, LenB(newMyType)
    End If

    CloseHandle hMMF

End Function

'Read from MyMMF
Private Function readMyType(ByRef inMyType As myType)

    hMMF = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, False, "MyMMF")

    If hMMF = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data in MyMMF"
        Exit Function
    Else
        pMemfile = MapViewOfFile(hMMF, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0)
        RtlMoveMemory2 ByVal inMyType, pMemfile, LenB(inMyType)
    End If

    CloseHandle hMMF

End Function


'Declares and Constants
Public Type myType
    a As Integer
    b(5) As Boolean
    d(15) as Double
End Type


Public Declare Function OpenFileMapping Lib "kernel32" Alias "OpenFileMappingA" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Integer, ByVal bInheritHandle As Integer, ByVal lpName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function CreateFileMapping Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileMappingA" (ByVal hFile As Long, ByVal lpAttributes As Long, ByVal flProtect As Integer, ByVal dwMaximumSizeHigh As Integer, ByVal dwMaximumSizeLow As Integer, ByVal lpName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function MapViewOfFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFileMappingObject As Long, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal dwFileOffsetHigh As Long, ByVal dwFileOffsetLow As Long, ByVal dwNumberOfBytesToMap As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Public Declare Sub RtlMoveMemory1 Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
ByVal Destination As Long, _
ByRef Source As Any, _
ByVal Length As Long)

Public Declare Sub RtlMoveMemory2 Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
ByRef Destination As Any, _
ByVal Source As Long, _
ByVal Length As Long)

Public Const FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F
Public Const PAGE_READWRITE = &H4
```

Comment: Nice idea, especially for bulkier transfers.

Answer (score 1):

If they are two threads (each with their own window? in VB6? hmm) then you just need to send a pointer to the variable `VarPtr(blah)` and make sure you copy out in the window procedure before returning.

If however, the threads are in two separate processes, you have far fewer options.

You can either use the `WM_COPYDATA` message which does the marshalling for you, or setup some shared/global memory and pass pointer/offsets via a normal `SendMessage()`
Normal thread sync practices apply to the latter methods.

Comment: Multiple threads in the same process. Assume I use varptr(blah) to send a pointer to my object to the client; how do I dereference the pointer (long) to user-defined type on the receiving side?

Comment: RtlMoveMemory2 tmp2, VarPtr(tmp), LenB(tmp2). That will copy tmp to tmp2 if tmp and tmp2 are in the same process's memory space. If your trying to go inter-process use my answer. RtlMoveMemory2 is defined is my answer.